# How to make a Beep sound in C on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, audio

I am trying to make a program which includes a beep noise. I work on a 32 bit Windows Vista. I am using the Code::Blocks IDE which runs on a GNU compiler. My sample code is -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dos.h>

int main(void)
{
    Beep(750, 300);
    printf("\n \n \t This is a dummy program for Beep.");
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

On the Internet I read that we could also use \a in printf to make a beep. I tried that but it is not working. I checked my speakers and sound card. Everything is perfect but I hear no beep. Even the method I displayed in my sample code does not work.

Comment: In C, writing `'\a'` to standard output is not required to produce an audible signal. Are you looking for a Windows-specific answer?

Comment: `Beep` works fine but probably requires a message loop

Comment: is `Beep` returning a non-zero value?

Comment: `dos.h` is for DOS, not for Windows.

Comment: have you tried: printf("\a");  If you insist on Windows, then https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: [toot](http://github.com/vareille/toot) is a cross-platform C file and command line tool that try to call several sound generators to produce the beep

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C standard [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207064/2738262) that writing `'\a'` to standard output produce an audible or visible alert signal, but it will not work if standard output is redirected. Likewise, some newer computers lack the PC beeper on which Windows `Beep()` and some terminals rely. To cause a Windows PC to play an alert sound in a desktop application, you can call the Windows-specific [`MessageBeep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which plays a sound "asynchronously" (in the background while your program continues to run). The user can configure which sound is associated with each of these four values in the Sound control panel.

```
#include <windows.h>

/* Include one of these in a function */
MessageBeep(MB_OK);              /* play Windows default beep */
MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION); /* play asterisk sound */
MessageBeep(MB_ICONQUESTION);    /* play question sound */
MessageBeep(MB_ICONWARNING);     /* play warning sound */
```

`MessageBeep()` is defined in `User32.dll`, so if this gives you link errors, make sure you're linking to the corresponding import library. In MinGW GCC (the compiler in Code::Blocks), add `-lUser32` to the list of libraries passed to the linker.

Comment: Hint for future readers: When I quickly tried this, I got link errors, and had to add `User32.dll` to the linking. Most IDE-generated Windows projects probably include it, but if not, find a way to add it for your dev env (I needed to add `LIBS =+ -lUser32` to *qmake* .pro file of my test project, for example).

Comment: Hello Tepples,Thank you for the answer.Does this mean that like in My sample program, instead I using Beep(); I should use MessageBeep(MB_OK); to produce a default windows beep.

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageBeep(-1);
```

From the MSDN documentation:

> **MessageBeep function**
>
> Plays a waveform sound. The waveform sound for each sound type is
>   identified by an entry in the registry.
>
> `BOOL WINAPI MessageBeep(   _In_  UINT uType );`
>   ... ...
>
> Value for `uType`: `0xFFFFFFFF`
>
> Meaning: A simple beep. If the
>   sound card is not available, the sound is generated using the speaker.

---

Also, and to my surprise, I've tested that. at least Windows 7 32 bits (and Windows Vista surely too) do some sort of emulation for the old 8253 I/O ports and the keyboard port, available to ring 3 processes, so the old implementation of `sound()` and `nosound()` should work. Unfornately, I haven't got any 32 bit machine available ATM so I cannot confirm this.

Comment: Hello, The answer is not working in my program as my compiler is giving error - BOOL WINAPI undeclared. In my IDE it is not working.Please can you test your method once more so that no other users get wrong answers.

Comment: I have included many headers. I have even included windows.h and dos.h

Comment: How are you using MessageBeep? Please write the exact line from your program in which MessageBeep is used

Comment: I am not using MessageBeep as a line.I have declared it and then I am calling it.

Comment: You don't have to declare it. Windows.h already declares it. Just call it whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

For the [`Beep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in windows.h to actually work, you have to have a "PC speaker" buzzer in your PC, as stated in the function's documentation. So you need to have a fairly old PC and with Windows XP or older, since support for the function was apparently dropped in Windows Vista.

On newer Windows versions, calling `Beep()` gives a beep in the speakers instead, using your sound card. If you aren't getting any beep, it is possibly not related to the program, but perhaps to your specific computer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Beep does work again in Windows since windows 7. The format is:

```
Beep(frequency, duration) where frequency is the pitch in hertz, and duration is the length in milliseconds
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This one works to on Windows 7 compiled with Visual Studio 2017. No problems with that.

```
printf("\n Bad request - check status code parameter\a");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `\a`. At least it works in my computer.

Comment: The question says they tried that and it doesn't work.