# \a (Alarm and beep) escape sequence character not working in C language

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I don't know why `\a` is not working. My code is working and displays in terminal. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\a");
    return 0;
}
```

My IDE: **Visual Studio Code**

My Compiler: **Mingw gcc**

Comment: Please tell how you run the code. Perhaps even a *screenshot* would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `\a` depends on the environment/terminal you use.

My guess is that Windows does not implement it or perhaps it is disabled for some reason. There is not much you can do unless you use platform-specific APIs that play a specific sound.

See [How to make a Beep sound in C on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493837/how-to-make-a-beep-sound-in-c-on-windows)

Comment: conhost.exe (which is the console that cmd and powershell connects to) does support beep. Try echo "\`a", `echo [char]7` or `cmd /c "echo $([char]7)"` in powershell and you'll hear a sound. Or type `echo ` then Ctrl+G or Alt+7 in cmd and you'll see the same effect

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for the details! It has been a while since I used Windows. I recall having heard the beep many years ago over there, but I was not sure if it was from the terminal or if it was still enabled by default. In any case, relying on `\a` to make the sound is not a great idea, so I decided to link the other question.

Comment: I don't think modern motherboards come with a buzzer, so modern versions of Windows will use speakers instead. Too bad, the buzzer era is some major nostalgia. (Real computers should sound like BEEP beep-beep-beep-BEEP BEEP when booting.)